# Buttons vs code editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, button, atom-editor

I have recently downloaded vs code editor to replace atom which I have been using and the only editor I have ever used I am new to coding so please bear with me.  So I copied the code written in atom from one of my projects and pasted it to vs code and installed live server to open the code onto a web page on my computer but when I was using atom I have a button on my page and when clicked took me to another page of my web site. When I open the main page using live server on vs code it opens the main page but when I click the button to open another page of my site nothing happens. I have clicked to open the second page from my vs code account using the live server and it opens no problem just wondering how to get it to open when the button is clicked on the we page?
Any idea’s

Comment: if you use a webserver you would have no problems, probably Live Server is only a push server that handles changes of the current page

Answer (score 0):

If it is a HTML button element, you should provide onClick event and then use some javascript to navigate to another location. Something like:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/link-to-your-page'">Button name</button>
```

If it is an anchor tag, then you should provide 'href' attribute. Paste your code to get more insight ;)

Comment: I have href attribute added as it is an anchor tag and like I said it works when using the atom editor. I have only just started using vs code as I have read that atom is going to be discontinued as of December 2022 so trying to get to grips with vs code everything opens up I have one page called my details and on there there is a button named my hobbies when I click the button on the page opened using atom editor it take you to the my hobbies page the code is exactly the same as it’s been copy and pasted onto the vs code editor but just the button does nothing

Comment: Changing code editor should not have any effects on the outcome, please paste your html code here